# Locale-aware number-string formatting in .NET

Tags: .net, internationalization, globalization

Different languages have different rules related to writing down numbers (counts etc.). For instance:

| Polish | English |
| --- | --- |
| 1 plik | 1 file |
| 2 pliki | 2 files |
| 3 pliki | 3 files |
| 4 pliki | 4 files |
| 5 plików | 5 files |
| 6 plików | 6 files |
| ... | ... |
| 20 plików | 20 files |
| 21 plików | 21 files |
| 22 pliki | 22 files |
| ... | ... |

Android has a very nice mechanism, which takes multiple string variants, a value and picks proper string based on specific locale's settings.

Is there similar mechanism for .NET, which would work for different locales?

Answer (score 0):

.NET itself doesn't have such mechanism. But there are 3rd party libraries, which helps solving this issue, such as [SmartFormat](https://github.com/axuno/SmartFormat).